# Java regular expressions - what is wrong with this code

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract the name of a property referenced in a string using the `$()` construct. For instance, if `bb=xo-xo`, then `"aa$(bb)aa"` expands to `"aaxo-xoaa"`.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String PROPERTY_NAME_REGEX = "\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)*";
  final String PROPERTY_REFERENCE_REGEX = "\\$\\((" + PROPERTY_NAME_REGEX + ")\\)";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PROPERTY_REFERENCE_REGEX);
  String value = "hhh $(aa.bbcc.dd) @jj $(aakfd) j";
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("\"%s\" at [%d-%d)",
      matcher.group(),
      matcher.start(),
      matcher.end()));
    for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); ++i) {
      System.out.println(String.format("group[%d] = %s", i, matcher.group(i)));
    }
  }
}
```

And it displays:

```
"$(aa.bbcc.dd)" at [4-17)
group[0] = $(aa.bbcc.dd)
"$(aakfd)" at [22-30)
group[0] = $(aakfd)
```

But I was hoping to get the following output:

```
"$(aa.bbcc.dd)" at [4-17)
group[0] = aa.bbcc.dd
"$(aakfd)" at [22-30)
group[0] = aakfd
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: "Beauty is in the eyes of the beholder".

Comment: take a look at the for loop. The groups index begin with 1 for the parenthesis enclosed matches

Comment: Sorry for being a smartass. You should use a parser for this, not regex.. You could take a look at the `ExpandProperties` class from ant, which does exactly this type of replacements.

Comment: Agreed. I have another question  -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558411/is-there-such-a-thing-as-static-jar-linking-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group 0 is always the entire match, regardless of any specified capturing groups. To top this off, Matcher.groupCount() returns the number of capturing groups, excluding the entire match. To get the result you were after, change your for loop to the following (notice that it starts at 1, and continues one step further due to the added equal sign):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific problem, you should be looking at `group[1]`, not `group[0]`.

The `Matcher.groupCount()` method does not include `group[0]` in the count, thus your for loop is never showing you the `group[1]` matches because `i < matcher.groupCount()` is false.

Change your condition to `i <= matcher.groupCount()` and your output will be more enlightening.

That said, there are better ways of doing this than writing your own regex - e.g. http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/ExpandProperties.html

Comment: Agreed. I have another question  -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558411/is-there-such-a-thing-as-static-jar-linking-in-java